# How to get Datagrid view cell value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Using VB.NET

How to get Datagridview cell value.

I want to insert a Datagridcell value in the table, How to get datagridview cell value.

Need vb.net code Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an ID column called IDTextBoxColumn. You can get the value for each row like this:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In MyDataGridView.Rows
    Console.WriteLine("ID value is " & row.Cells(IDTextBoxColumn.Index).Value.ToString())
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Domain.Master.Product product = new Domain.Master.Product();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (dr.Cells[0].Value == null)
                { }
                else
                {
                    ProductViewModel pvm =roduct.ProductDetails(dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    dr.Cells[3].Value = pvm.PCode.ToString();
                    dr.Cells[4].Value = pvm.Pdtcatagory;
                }
            }
```